# Mandrill template not looping on array

Tags: python, email, templates, mandrill

I am trying to send array of items to the `Mandrill` template, but It's not working, the mail I receive shows the loop itself instead the data.

Here's my python code:

```py
message = {
    'text': '',
    'html': '',
    'preserve_recipients': False,
    'to': [
        {
            'email': 'rohit@email.com',
            'name': 'Rohit Khatri',
            'type': 'to'
        }
    ],
    'merge_vars': [
        {
            'rcpt': 'rohit@email.com',
            'vars': [
                {
                    'name': 'name',
                    'content': 'Rohit Khatri'
                },
                {
                    'name': 'email',
                    'content': 'rohit@email.com'
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    'global_merge_vars': [
        {
            'name': 'notifications',
            'content': [
                {
                    'name': 'Rohit Khatri',
                    'profile_picture': 'http://rohitkhatri.com/profile_picture.jpg'
                },
                {
                    'name': 'John Doe',
                    'profile_picture': 'http://johndoe.com/profile_picture.jpg'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

api = Mandrill('MANDRILL_KEY')
api.messages.send_template(
    template_name = 'notification',
    template_content = {},
    message = message
)
```

Here's the template code:

```html
{{#each notifications}}
<tr class="item">
    <td valign="top" class="textContent">
        <img src="{{profile_picture}}" width="50" height="75" class="itemImage"/>
        <h4 class="itemName">{{name}}</h4>
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

And this is the output I'm getting on email:

```html
{{#notifications}}
{{name}}
{{/notifications}}
```

It's not executing the loop, don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck with this same problem i added 'merge_language'=>'handlebars' in the message object and it solved my problem.